# What does #$ do in bash? (aka: Hash dollar sign, pound dollar sign)

Tags: bash, shell

I came across this expression in a bash script and it's really not easy to google for.

```
#$...
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/247127/what-is-and-in-linux

Comment: If #$ is not a typo then AFAIK it is a comment line, if you meant $# then its the number of arguments passed to the script or the function

Comment: how about attaching the site where you found it?

Comment: Try to search for "dollar pound" or "pound dollar", that was how I did to find this page (first result of Google).

Comment: You can also open the `bash` manpage and search for the patterns you meet but don't know the name of by typing `/` then the characters (don't forget to escape them). It may not be enough explanation, but at least you'll know their name, so it's easier to google them up.

Comment: About googling: This works nowadays: google for --> bash "$#"  <-- actually, this was the top answer ;-)

Answer (score 60):

`#$` does "nothing", as `#` is starting comment and everything behind it on the same line is ignored (with the notable exception of the ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)).

`$#` is a variable containing the number of arguments passed to a shell script (like `$*` is a variable containing all arguments).

Answer (score 29):

In bash this is generally a comment, everything after the hash (on the same line) is ignored.
However, if your bash script is being passed to something unusual it could be interpreted by that.

For instance, if you submit a script to the Sun Grid Engine:

> Any line beginning with hash-dollar, i.e., `#$`, is a special comment which is understood by SGE to specify something about how or where the job is run. In this case we specify the directory in which the job is to be run (`#$ -cwd`) and the queue which the job will join (`#$ -q serial.q`).

(source: [http://talby.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/~rcs/_linux_and_hpc_lib/sge_intro.html](http://talby.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ercs/_linux_and_hpc_lib/sge_intro.html))

Comment: This was the use case I found it in - SGE. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I just came across a `#$` in a script and was wondering the same thing. There is answer which was not mentioned yet: In bash search and replace (see [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)).

Normally, it works like this:

```
${PARAMETER/PATTERN/STRING}
```

`PATTERN` can also include *anchors*, to match it either at the beginning or the end; namely `#` and `%`:

```
MYSTRING=ABCCBA
echo ${MYSTRING/#A/y}  # RESULT: yBCCBA
echo ${MYSTRING/%A/y}  # RESULT: ABCCBy
```

You can also use a variable for `PATTERN` - *and* skip the slashes to add to the confusion (and replace the pattern match with an empty string):

```
echo ${MYSTRING#$PATTERN}  # RESULT: BCCBA
echo ${MYSTRING%$PATTERN}  # RESULT: ABCCB
```

And here it is, a `#$` in a bash string.

Answer (score 10):

It could be possible that the intended expression was  **$#** instead of **#$**

**$#**  Stores the number of command-line arguments that were passed to the shell program.

for example:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "${USAGE}" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Displays the message stored in the $USAGE variable if the number of command-line arguments is 0.

Answer (score 6):

One place where you might see `#$` come up is inside a arithmetic expression when changing base: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic

For example `echo $((2#101))` will convert `101` to base two, and print `5`.

I recently used this here:

```
calculate_time() {
    minutes=$((${1:0:1} + ${1:9:1}))
    seconds=$((${1:2:1} + ${1:11:1}))
    milliseconds=$((10#${1:4:3} + 10#${1:13:3}))
    result=$((${minutes}*60*1000 + ${seconds}*1000 + ${milliseconds}))
    echo $result
}
```

The first argument (`$1`) was in some format I don't remember that was taken using `awk`. The milliseconds argument was parsed as `009`, for 9 milliseconds. However, bash treats numbers starting with a leading 0 as octal, so I converted them to decimal. It's not exactly using `#$`, but when I looked at this code after a while and tried to remember what was going on, I thought that was an expression at first and found this question, so this might help someone else.

Comment: Funny enough, even SO can't display this correctly. It also doesn't display correctly on github. It looks fine in Sublime Text though.

Comment: I've found [this function](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/caff704f41d7a8cd01aa54b1202d6e3123e33fe6/lib/functions.zsh#L135-L189) in the oh my zsh repo, and I can't understand what the following syntax is doing `ord=$(( [##16] #byte ))`. I think it is similar to the above, but wanted to know exactly what was happening. I'm guessing it's base16 conversion?