# linux - shellscript - "$#"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shellscript with the following lines:

```
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o xtrace

if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
then
   echo 'A message'
   exit 1
fi
```

Can somebody explain the commands, in particular the setter and the `"$#"` portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$#` is the number of arguments passed to the script.

So this

```
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
```

check ensures that if no arguments are passed then the script exits, 
which implies that the script expects one or more arguments.

---

In a simple script called `my_script`, have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $#
```

and run with:

```
$ ./my_script # prints 0
$ ./my_script a b cde  # prints 3
$ ./my_script 1 2 3 4 # prints 4
```

---

The set built-in options:

`set -o unset` (equivalent to `set -u`): Treats unset variable as error.

`set -o errexit` (equivalent to `set -e`): Exits immediately on error.

`set -o xtrace` (equivalent to `set -x`): Displays the expanded command. Typically used to to debug shell scripts.

Consider a simple script called `opt` to demonstrate this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
set -x

cmd="ps $$"
${cmd}

echo $var # 'var' is unset. So it's an "error". Since we have
          # 'set -o e', the script exits.
echo "won't print this
```

"

outputs something like:

```
+ cmd='ps 2885'
+ ps 2885
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 2885 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./s
./s: line 9: var: unbound variable
```

The first two lines in the output (starting with `+`) are due to `set -x`.
The next two are the result of running the `${cmd}`.
The next line is the error, happened as the result of `set -u`.

You can read more about the [set built-in options here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin).

Comment: great answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, $# keeps the number of command line arguments. In your case, the conditional part will fire only when there are some.

I believe very similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630203/what-does-do-in-bash-aka-hash-dollar-sign-pound-dollar-sign), second or third answer matching your problem.